# Azure Insights Request logs

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights, core-api

I'm trying to see inside the azure Insights the request information inside an error or exception. 
What I'm looking for is when an error happened in my API, be able to check the error information (which azure does very good) but as well be able to see the information inside the request who triggers the error.

Does someone know if this is possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application Insights dosen't do that by default.
but you can do that easily using a custom logger implemented as interceptor in your application as a .net core middle ware i have done that on my blog check it will help
[here](https://ahmedzthoughts.wordpress.com/2018/11/07/adding-custom-log-properties-to-application-insights-request-telemetry-using-custom-net-core-middle-ware/)
hope it helps.